# Libgdx - Building dynamic 3d models with Modelbuilder/MeshPartBuilder while rendering

Tags: libgdx, performance, opengl-es2, 3d-meshes, multithreading

**Context:** I'm building a mobile game targeted for android with libgdx. It's an endless highscore based game. The environment/terrain is build dynamically. It's kind of a maze/wall/block terrain. I'm using the ModelBuilder and MeshPartBuilder API of libgdx to create the model.

**Problem:** As the game is endless and the terrain random, I need to build the model while rendering preferably at consistent 60fps. I have put the generation code into a worker thread. This works, but the end() method of the ModelBuilder has to be called in the rendering thread, because of the needed opengl context.

Even if I only build a single rectangle using meshpartbuilder, I get a huge framedrop from calling ModelBuilder.end() .

**Codesnippet:**

```
// we are in a worker thread
modelBuilder.begin(); // ModelBuilder instance
MeshPartBuilder wallBuilder = modelBuilder.part("mazePart", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, modelMaterial);

... create some meshes with MeshPartBuilder ...

Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Model model = modelBuilder.end(); // method that causes a framedrop from 60 to ~35
        activeModels.add(model);
    }
});
```

**Question:** How do I achieve stable fps while building models dynamically in libgdx? Is it even possible?